# How to bind a (static) Dictionary to Labels?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, dictionary

I have a static Dictionary

```
class X { static Dictionary<string,string> MyDict {get { ... }} }
```

This Dictionary contains Data i want to show in a Grid-Control:

```
<Grid>
  <!-- Row and Column-Definitions here -->
  <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding MyDict.Key=="foo" }" ToolTip="foo" />
  <!-- some more labels -->
</Grid>
```

1.) i dont know how to get access (in xaml) to the dictionary

2.) i want to bind the Value of a specified key to the Content-Property of the Label.

how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a [converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) which will allow you to extract your value out of the `Dictionary` via the `ConverterParameter`.

```
public class DictConverter: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Dictionary<string,string> data = (Dictionary<string,string>)value;
        String parameter = (String)parameter;
        return data[parameter];
    }
}
```

The XAML would be as follows...

```
<Window.Resources>
    <converters:DictConverter x:Key="MyDictConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>

Content="{Binding MyDictProperty, Converter={StaticResource MyDictConverter}, ConverterParameter=foo}"
```

Comment: That's totally overkill, since the XAML parser is capable of using indexers.

Comment: @Tobias It's not overkill, it's separation of concerns.

Comment: IMO it is, since you are creating a class (with all overhead that brings) for the sake of simply simulating indexer access, which is already built in.

Comment: And what would those concerns you are supposedly separating be?

Comment: @H.B. Type knowledge within the XAML. It feels hackish IMHO even if supported. If the container (Dictionary) changes down the road I can adjust my single converter and be done. It pushes the decision making to a single place.

Comment: @AaronMcIver: Don't you then up with a converter that does not what it says it does, or what exactly do you mean by "changes"? I see no problem with using the binding indexers, it's not any different than accessing a sub-property. How would a change negatively affect that?

Comment: @H.B. If the property within the ViewModel which is a Dictionary<K, V> changes to a List<T>, anyone using that ViewModel will need to change their XAML accordingly. If everyone is using a Converter and the logic is being done within the Converter (doing the work in ViewModel would also work in this instance) then all that needs adjusted is the Converter. To be honest, I would adjust my exposed property in the VieWModel in this instance and skip the Converter all together however I feel the Converter over the indexer is a better choice if the property must be a Dictionary<K, V>.

Comment: @AaronMcIver: You'd still have to replace the parameters in the xaml if you use _any_ kind of converter parameter in the new implementation which differs from the original one, so your argument is still invalid (I think). Furthermore your approach doesn't allow for any value transformations other than StringFormat, which makes it even less useful.

Comment: @Tobias The ConverterParameter would be used to make the decision within the _container_. I can return whatever I want from the value (Dictionary<K, V>) being passed in which will be pushed into the Content property of the Label. Remember that the ConverterParameter is being used in this case to _make_ the decision.

Comment: @AaronMcIver: Now I finally see your point... But wouldn't changing some string indexed collection to an int based one be impossible to maintain if you just hack in some XAML obfuscating mapping function? Then it would be easier to go through the pain of replacing all usages once and retaining the overall maintainability of the app.

Comment: @AaronMcIver: In return you get the semantical incorrectness of applying a converter to something that does not need to be converted. I for one would use all the binding accessors there are, if there are changes things always need to be changed and depending on the location and distribution the effort may differ but it's probably something i could live with...

Comment: @Tobias As stated earlier, I would do all this within a ViewModel, avoiding the XAML _hacking_ as a whole.

Comment: @AaronMcIver I wouldn't exactly call utilising XAML indexers `hacking`, it is an intended feature and was designed for use in situations like this.

Answer (score 4):

To get access to the Dictionary, you have to do something like this (if your DataContext isn't already an instance of `X`):

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.DataContext>
        <X xmlns="clr-namespace:Your.Namespace" />
    </Grid.DataContext>
    <!-- other code here -->
</Grid>
```

To access the values in the dictionary, your binding has to look as follows:

```
<Label Content="{Binding MyDict[key]}" />
```

Comment: `MyDict` is a static, would this binding work correctly? Having an instance of X should be unnecessary.

Comment: You need an instance to tell the binding engine the type of your class, else it wouldn't be able to know where to find the binding target.

Comment: If you could take a look at my answer, I think that should achieve the desired result, without instantiating an instance of X.

Comment: What is capital X in this case?

Comment: @KalaJ: The type the OP wanted to access a property of.

Answer (score 4):

Your binding will need to change to be the following:

```
Content="{Binding Path=[foo], Source={x:Static local:X.MyDict}}"
```

If you look at [Binding Paths](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752300.aspx#Path_Syntax) from the MSDN, you will see that string indexers can be specified in XAML. `local` will be the xmlns representing the namespace `X` resides in.

Comment: Can I ask you a few questions? What is meant by local? I get the error The namespace prefix local is not defined and the big X I assume is the ViewModel where I have my list present.

Answer (score 0):

I voted up Aaron for the converter and Tobias for indexers, but to actually access the *static dictionary*, try duplicating the property at the instance level and binding to that

```
// Code
class X 
{ 
    protected static Dictionary<string,string> StaticDict { get { ... } } 
    public Dictionary<string, string> InstanceDict { get { return StaticDict; } } 
} 

// Xaml
Content="{Binding InstanceDict, Converter = ... } "
```

Comment: That's not necessary, since you can bind to both static and instance properties, as long as your data context is of the needed type.