# wpf binding label content to a sorted list entry

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0

Not sure this is possible. I am trying to to bind a label content to global sorted list entry.

```
public class AppObj
{
  public static SortedList<string, string> Messages { get; set; }
  ......
}

AppObj.Messages = new SortedList<string, string>();
foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in entries)
{
  string key = entry.Key.ToString();
  string value = (string)entry.Value;
  if (AppObj.Messages.ContainsKey(key)) { AppObj.Messages.Add(key, value); }
  else { AppObj.Messages[key] = value; }
}
```

In xaml

```
<Label Content="{Binding AppObj.Messages["mykey"]}" />
```

The double quote inside the [] gives error.

How can I go around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `mykey` in the example is a hardcoded key name, then simply create a property which will expose the link into the data for the key "mykey". Then simply bind to that property.

```
 public string ViewableMessage { return AppObj.Messages["mykey"]; }
```

**Xaml**

```
 <Label Content="{Binding ViewableMessage }" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [IValueConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter(v=vs.110).aspx).  The SO post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8759226/3407841) shows a converter that does similar enough work for a Dictionary. Modify it to expect a SortedList and it looks like this:

```
public class SortedListConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        SortedList<string, string> data = (SortedList<string, string>)value;
        String parame = (String)parameter;
        return data[parame];
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Add this to your window resources:

```
 <local:SortedListConverter x:Key="cvtr"/>
```

and then bind like so:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource AppObj}, 
    Path=Messages,  
    Converter={StaticResource cvtr}, 
    ConverterParameter=key}" />
```