# How to bind static Dictionary Value to TextBox based on key in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a dictionary collection. I want to bind the dictionary value to label based on key. My dictionary is like this,

```
public Dictionary<string, IValue> MyCollection { get; set; }
```

**IValue**

```
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Rank { get; set; }
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

`<Label Content={Name, Source={x:Static MyCollection[P1]}}/>`

Please anyone give me a suggestion to done this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Two comments: 1. Your dictionary is not static. Why do you assume it is? 2. If you are sure, you have an entry in your collection which key is in fact the string "P1" you can bind to the Name property `<Label Content="{Binding MyCollection[P1].Name}" />`

Comment: @ChristianMurschall, I have tried  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8759226/9610968) this solution its now working fine. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm glad it worked, but in my opinion the solution in the link does add any value to my. But if its working for you - totally fine. In case you want to bind the key of the dictionary dynamicaly, [this solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13800383/4634044) is worth a look.